# Trouble setting text size in pixels

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I am having trouble setting text size in pixels for a new text layer.  Whatever I do I get the wrong size.  Here is a stripped down version of what I am doing: -

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;

app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.PIXELS;

var fontSize = 100;  //gives 416.67 px
//var fontSize = "100px"; -- same result

var txtLayerRef = docRef.artLayers.add();
txtLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
var textItemRef = txtLayerRef.textItem;
textItemRef.size = fontSize;
textItemRef.contents = "A text string";
```

It is essential that I am able to define my text size in pixels not points.  I am using Photoshop CC 2014 on Windows 7.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a proper UnitValue object to specify your size.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var txt = doc.activeLayer.textItem;
txt.size = new UnitValue(100, 'px');
```